# How to edit action list in WebStorm VCS operations popup?

Tags: webstorm

I want to add 'Merge Changes' into the VCS operations popup, but where to set up?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to modify VCS Operations popup ([IDEA-116464](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116464)), but you can create a custom Quick List (`Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Quick Lists`, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-quick-lists.html) with preferred actions. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116464#comment=27-1291948